# Who's the original Eobard Thawne who "fixes" New Earth's Eobard Thawne's life?

Tags: dc, comics

In Flash Vol 3 8 we're introduced to a version of the Eobard who has his life "fixed" by another version of himself.

This version of Eobard ought to come from a timeline where he became the Reverse Flash without having to have all of these fixes. Since otherwise he would never have been able to go back in the past and fix his life. How could Eobard go back in time to kill a brother he never knew existed?

Is it known at all where did this Flash come from and how he acquired his powers?